# rviz Plugin Tutorial crashes

Tags: rviz, ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have checked out the hydro rviz  visualization tutorials and compiled them without modification.

While running rviz, if I try to add an Imu visualization type to the display, rviz crashes with the following error:

```
rviz: /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/OgreMain/src/OgreSceneManager.cpp:807: virtual Ogre::SceneNode* Ogre::SceneManager::createSceneNode(): Assertion `mSceneNodes.find(sn->getName()) == mSceneNodes.end()' failed.
```

Similarly, if I try to add a PlantFlag, I get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, with no additional info.

This only happens when I compile from source. It works fine when I run the pre-compiled binaries. Any thoughts as to why this might be occurring?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/130086/rviz-plugin-tutorial-crashes/) by [svozar](https://answers.ros.org/users/12056/svozar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2014-02-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-17**:
Without considering the actual error, are you sure that the you checked at the version of the tutorial that matches your install rviz verison? (correct branch)? Does you installed Ogre version match the one rviz is compiled with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to link against different OGRE versions, so getting rid of OGRE 1.8 fixed the problem.

---

Originally posted by [svozar](https://answers.ros.org/users/12056/svozar/) with karma: 26 on 2014-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0